# Do/while loop isn't executing properly

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Im sure I am missing something simple but I cannot get my do while loop to execute properly. I want it to run through the first time and keep going until the user inputs q. It currently executes once and then loops back up to ask what account to access and then does nothing. Any help or pointing me in the right direction so I can fix it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Crawford_Driver
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double input1;
        String accountChoice;
        String accountActivity;
        RegularAccount regAcct = new RegularAccount(0, .5);
        SavingsAccount savAcct = new SavingsAccount(0, .5);


        do{
            System.out.println("What account would you like to access(regular or savings)?" );
            accountChoice = keyboard.nextLine();

            if(accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("regular"))

                System.out.println("What action do you wish to perform(deposit, withdraw or monthly process)? ");
            accountActivity = keyboard.nextLine();

            if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("deposit"))
                {
                    System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");
                    input1= keyboard.nextDouble();
                    regAcct.deposit(input1);
                    System.out.println("Your balance is " + regAcct.getBalance() );
                }
            else if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("withdraw"))
                {
                    System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                    input1= keyboard.nextDouble();
                    regAcct.withdraw(input1);
                    System.out.println("Your balance is "+ regAcct.getBalance());
                }
            else if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("monthly process"))
                {
                    regAcct.monthlyProcess();
                }
            else {
                if (accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("savings"))

                    if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("deposit"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");
                            input1= keyboard.nextDouble();
                            savAcct.deposit(input1);
                            System.out.println("Your balance is " + savAcct.getBalance() );
                        }

                if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("withdraw"))

                    System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                input1= keyboard.nextDouble();
                savAcct.withdraw(input1);
                System.out.println("Your balance is "+ savAcct.getBalance());

            }
        }while (!accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure you read both options at the start; `accountChoice` and `accountActivity`. One issue with your code is the lack of `{` and `}` usage.

So it would be like...

```
do { // do below first before checking the while condition
    if(accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("regular")) 
    {
        // do your work.
    } else if (accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("savings")) 
    {
        // do the rest
    }
} while (!accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));
```

Below is the modified code.

```
public class Crawford_Driver
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double input1;
        String accountChoice;
        String accountActivity;
        RegularAccount regAcct = new RegularAccount(0, .5);
        SavingsAccount savAcct = new SavingsAccount(0, .5);


        do {
            System.out.println("What account would you like to access(regular or savings)?" );
            accountChoice = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What action do you wish to perform(deposit, withdraw or monthly process)? ");
            accountActivity = keyboard.nextLine();


            if(accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("regular")) { // LINE moved and BRACKET MISSING

                if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("deposit"))
                {
                    System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");
                    input1= keyboard.nextDouble();
                    regAcct.deposit(input1);
                    System.out.println("Your balance is " + regAcct.getBalance() );
                }
                else if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("withdraw"))
                {
                    System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                    input1= keyboard.nextDouble();
                    regAcct.withdraw(input1);
                    System.out.println("Your balance is "+ regAcct.getBalance());
                }
                else if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("monthly process"))
                {
                    regAcct.monthlyProcess();
                }
            } 
            else if (accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("savings")) 
            { // line changed &  BRACKET MISSING

                if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("deposit"))
                {
                    System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");
                    input1= keyboard.nextDouble();
                    savAcct.deposit(input1);
                    System.out.println("Your balance is " + savAcct.getBalance() );
                }
                else if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("withdraw")) 
                { // bracket missing

                    System.out.println("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                    input1= keyboard.nextDouble();
                    savAcct.withdraw(input1);
                    System.out.println("Your balance is "+ savAcct.getBalance());
               }
           }
       } while (!accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a set of curly braces after this statement:

```
if(accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("regular"))
```

...and this statement:

```
 if (accountActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("withdraw"))
```

The default behavior for Java (and C, and C++) is to execute only the *next* line after an `if`, `for`, or `while` statement if curly braces are omitted.

When you're done, your statement should look like this:

```
if(accountChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("regular")) {
    System.out.println("What action do you wish to perform(deposit, withdraw or monthly process)? ");
    accountActivity = keyboard.nextLine();
    // Rest of code that concerns activity with a "regular" account
}
```

Comment: I went back and added the missing braces however now it loops through and asks what account to access and immediately asks how much to deposit without waiting on any user input. 
Here is the output of the program:
What account would you like to access(regular or savings)?
regular
What action do you wish to perform(deposit, withdraw or monthly process)? 
deposit
How much would you like to deposit?
44
Your balance is 44.0
What account would you like to access(regular or savings)?
How much would you like to deposit?

Comment: I undershot with my example - your curly braces should be wrapping everything that you wish to do in a specific context (namely, "regular").